# Does Django request.REQUEST.get() contain BOTH GET and POST parameters?

Tags: python, django, post, get

Are the parameters in request.POST and request.GET BOTH in request.REQUEST ? Or i have to check for each of them ?

I can't find a clear info in the documentation for both REQUEST/QueryDict.
NB: Django 1.4 Final

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this was possible in older versions but was depreciated in Django 1.7. For Django archeologists running ancient versions, keep reading.

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.REQUEST):

HttpRequest.REQUEST

For convenience, a dictionary-like object that searches POST first, then GET. Inspired by PHP’s $_REQUEST.

For example, if GET = {"name": "john"} and POST = {"age": '34'}, REQUEST["name"] would be "john", and REQUEST["age"] would be "34".

It’s strongly suggested that you use GET and POST instead of REQUEST, because the former are more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not sure which you need to use, if can be handy to replace with this :

```
def get_post_or_get(request):
    """
    Return the equivalent of request.REQUEST 
    which has been removed in Django 1.9
    """
    return request.POST or request.GET
```

reference : 
https://github.com/edx/django-openid-auth/pull/5/commits/aa5eef791cd487eb359db25011572d5966a2c92a

Comment: If you're feeling adventurous you could use `getattr(request, request.method)` :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the doc says:

> HttpRequest.REQUEST For convenience, a dictionary-like object that
>   searches POST first, then GET. Inspired by PHP’s $_REQUEST.
>
> For example, if GET = {"name": "john"} and POST = {"age": '34'},
>   REQUEST["name"] would be "john", and REQUEST["age"] would be "34".
>
> It’s strongly suggested that you use GET and POST instead of REQUEST,
>   because the former are more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

name = request.GET.get('name', request.POST.get('name'))

Comment: To match the previous functionality, you should invert the GET and POST to make post the priority. So:  name = request.POST.get('name', request.GET.get('name'))